# Facebook app infinite scroll issue

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-canvas, infinite-scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to use infinite scroll on a Facebook app we're currently building, however it will not work due to being in an iframe.

Has anyone come up with a work around for this or a similar situation.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll